# Do you know what is the ribbon connector is used here?

Tags: connector, identification

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SZwJ.jpg)https://gbatemp.net/threads/nand-flash-dump-3ds-xl.350668/page-68#post-4931791
I'm interested on the connectors on the SDcard, it seems to allow terminated ribbon cables. what is the connector used?
[[image]]

Comment: I can't be sure from that picture, but it may be an FFC ("Flat Flexible Cable") connector.

Comment: @bitsmack are you sure that ffc connector allows flat ribbon cables to connect?

Comment: Nope! I couldn't tell from the picture if it was terminated as a flex cable assembly.

Comment: I can see a black retaining arm on the connector. Looks like FFC to me.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to measure the pitch and all the mechanical stops to determine the connector type.

[example](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/samtec-inc/IDSD-03-D-06.00-T/SAM8734-ND/3476372) of a ribbon cable

[examples of FPC connectors](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/connectors-interconnects/ffc-fpc-flat-flexible-connectors/1442849?k=&pkeyword=&pv1747=6&pv88=7&FV=fff40016%2Cfff80421&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=500). not easy to match.